# Disciplining a TCXO from a broadcast reference source

Tags: rf, frequency, pll

In the UK (and much of europe), a broadcast time and frequency reference is available in the form of the [MST radio time signal](http://www.npl.co.uk/science-technology/time-frequency/products-and-services/time/msf-radio-time-signal). This is broadcast using on-off keying on a frequency of 60 kilohertz, to within one part in 10^12.

I'd like to use this signal to construct a cheap and accurate 10MHz frequency reference. My tentative plan is to construct a PLL, with a VCTCXO as the VCO component, and lock it to the 60KHz reference. That's the easy part.

However, I'm not sure how to approach a couple of other aspects of the solution. Specifically:

- What's the easiest way to receive and amplify the 60KHz carrier wave, producing a clean 60KHz square wave output from the receiver?
- How should I handle the periods during which the transmitter is not sending the carrier wave (which can last up to 500ms, at the beginning of each minute)? I don't want the phase comparator to decide the clock is way out of phase and skew the TCXO frequency during this period.

Comment: Have you considered using GPS? U-blox make timing modules that pretty much do all of this for you.

Comment: @Jon I have, but I'd like it to work indoors, which is easy for MST, but not for GPS.

Comment: Farnell sell a 60kHz tuning fork crystal, if you want to try a crystal filter or a direct conversion receiver. I haven't found time to experiment with it myself.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I don't know much about RF, but I don't want to demodulate the signal at all, just isolate and amplify (and square it up). I don't think a direct conversion receiver would work for that.

Comment: i would like to see an answer to this question! If my wristwatch can receive the timecode from this signal then it can surely be received on a very small antenna. *edit* I found this reference about antennas for 60kHz. I'm sure by now you have already solved this issue... perhaps you can share with us and provide your own answer!